# Visualización pública de aplicación en google cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine

Actualmente tengo un servidor en google cloud platform, el sistema operativo es ubuntu; En esta maquina tengo una aplicación python web, quería saber si había alguna manera de hacer publica esa aplicación, que pudiera ser visualizada desde una url.

Saludos

Comment: Tengo una duda, dices que tienes un servidor pero tienes el tag de `google-app-engine`, ¿No tendría que ser más bien `google-compute-engine`?

Answer (score 1):

Si ya tienes la instancia, puedes crear las reglas del firewall a pata, es decir, yendo al panel de VPC network -> firewall rules y crear una regla de firewall que permite el tráfico de datos a través bajo el puerto tcp en los puertos que desees, ya sea el 80, 8080, o 443. Además cambia el source ip para que te permita usar la ip 0.0.0.0 y así estén disponibles todas tus interfaces.

La otra es que puedes utilizar el cliente de `gcloud`.

```
gcloud compute firewall-rules create <nombre de la regla> \
    --action allow \
    --target-tags "<tag de tu instancia>" \
    --source-ranges "0.0.0.0/0" \
    --rules <protocolos>:<puertos> \
    --no-disabled \
    --enable-logging
```

Esto es suponiendo que tu instancia tiene un tag. Si no tiene un tag también se lo puedes añadir a pata, es decir vas a Compute Engine -> VM Instances, le das click al nombre de tu instancia y le das luego en editar detalles de tu instancia. Posteriormente agregas un tag de red, en caso de que no exista, y guardas la configuración

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cómo puedes ver en la imagen, por lo general ya vienen algunas instancias con esos tags de red, *http-server* y *https-server*, tu puedes eliminar o añadir los que quieras.

Otra forma de tener un tag de red es hacerlo con el cliente de gcloud.

```
gcloud compute instances \
    add-tags <Nombre de la instancia> \
    --tags=<escribe el tag que quieras>
```

Después de que tengas el tag de la instancia, ahora si puedes actuar como describí anteriormente para crear una regla de firewall.

Una ves que tengas la regla de firewall puedes crear otra o actualizarla con `gcloud compute firewall-rules update` o manualmente en la consola.

Ya que tengas la configuración que deseas en los puertos que quieres, ya puedes exponer los servicios que corras a través de esos puertos y protocolos configurados y podrás acceder a ellos desde la ip externa de la instancia y los puertos que hayas expuesto.

Answer (score 0):

Primer punto, ¿Tu servidor es un Compute Engine?

Sí es así, desde la instancia tendrías que activar el acceso http, en las opciones de la instancia editandola, o agregando un tag de red: http. allow-http.

Estos puertos se mapean automáticamente en el firewall a tu instancia, en este caso al servicio http, por lo que ya podría ser pública, por ende tu aplicación debe de estar corriendo en este puerto; que es 8080.

Google automaticamente te generará una ip externa desde la cual podrás acceder a tu instancia, recuerda, esta ip es ephemeral, por lo tanto cada que apagues y enciendas tu instancia esta misma se reseteará; si requieres una ip externa estática sería otro procedemiento.

:)